# My react native app wont build using github actions, and i dont know why

Tags: react-native, continuous-integration, github-actions

This is my YML file:

```
 on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build-and-publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Install EAS CLI
      run: npm install -g eas-cli

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: yarn install

    - name: Install Node.js
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: '14.x'
        
    - name: Install Expo CLI
      run: npm install -g expo-cli

    - name: Debug
      run: echo ${{ secrets.EXPO_USERNAME }} ${{ secrets.EXPO_PASSWORD }}

    - name: Install expect
      run: |
        sudo apt-get update
        sudo apt-get -y install expect
    - name: Expo login
      run: |
        export EAS_USERNAME="${{ secrets.EXPO_USERNAME }}"
        export EAS_PASSWORD="${{ secrets.EXPO_PASSWORD }}"
        expect -c '
          spawn eas login -u $env(EAS_USERNAME) -p $env(EAS_PASSWORD)
          expect {
            -exact "Email or username: " {
              send "$env(EAS_USERNAME)\r"
              exp_continue
            }
            -exact "Password: " {
              send "$env(EAS_PASSWORD)\r"
              exp_continue
            }
            eof
          }'
          
    - name: Install Expo CLI
      run: npm install -g expo-cli

    - name: Validate app.json
      run: expo config:validate

    - name: Build and Publish
      run: |
        eas build -p android \
          --no-publish \
          --release-channel default \
          --auto-clean \
          --keystore-path ../../my-release-key.keystore \
          --keystore-alias alias_name \
          --keystore-password ${{ secrets.KEYSTORE_PASSWORD }} \
          --key-password ${{ secrets.KEY_PASSWORD }} \
          --json-key android \
          --env "$(echo '${{ toJson(secrets) }}' | base64)"
```

And when I push it to my github repository, it runs, it does actually log into expo, but is doesnt build:

[image]

When i try building this without the arguments it tells me it isnt logged in. But the way i see it, it actually does all the steps, but not the building so please help me out!

Comment: According to [`eas build`](https://github.com/expo/eas-cli#eas-build) command, apparently those flags are not supported. Please verify if you're using the right command.